# How do I specify a version of Ruby for Rails without using RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xubuntu

How do I specify a version of Ruby for Rails **without using RVM**?

I am using Xubuntu 11.10, which comes with Ruby 1.8. I have installed Ruby 1.9 package, and updated the alternatives so `ruby -version` returns `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]`. Rails still seems to be using 1.8 however, so how can I tell it to use Ruby 1.9 instead? I don't want to uninstall Ruby 1.8 since that will remove a bunch of other stuff as well.

I know similar SO questions have been answered with "use RVM". I can't do this - it has a dependency on  `libreadline-gplv2-dev` package, which conflicts with `libreadline-dev` which `r-base-dev` depends on.

Comment: When you say "Rails still seems to be using 1.8" - do you mean the rails command or mod_passenger?

Comment: Rails command, specifically `rails server`. I am trying to run an app that (I think) uses version 1.9 hash syntax and I get errors like: 

    syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
      wrap_parameters format: [:json]
                             ^
     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'

Comment: I have a feeling that when you invoke the Rails commands, you are invoking 1.8's gem. Have you done `gem1.9 install rails`? And whats the output of `which rails`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems I need to update the gem command to use the 1.9 version as well as ruby, then I can install rails through that. But to install rails, I need the dev headers for ruby. The following commands should work for others:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
sudo update-alternatives --config gem
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: Exactly. But remember, if you really need to do some version switching, you still really need RVM. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Changing versions of ruby is a routine if you work with several projects. If you can't use rvm, try [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems your rubygems environment is using ruby 1.8 whereas you want your rails app to run in 1.9. You can find out by doing this:

```
$ ruby -version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

$ gem env | grep 'RUBY VERSION'
   - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Make sure your rubygems environment under which rails runs is running the version you want.